# FizzBuzz in angular?

Tags: angularjs, fizzbuzz

I am trying to learn Angular and I am trying to make a fizzBuzz however; I don't get result with 'both' conditions:

Here is the app:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("game", ["$scope", function($scope) {

$scope.number = 0;
$scope.result = "";

$scope.fizzBuzz = function(){

  if($scope.number){

      if($scope.number % 3 == 0)
      {
        return $scope.result = "Fizz";
      }
      else if($scope.number % 5 == 0)
      {
        return $scope.result = "Buzz";
      }
      else if(($scope.number % 3 == 0) && ($scope.number % 5 == 0))
      {
        return $scope.result = "FizzBuzz";
        alert($scope.result);
      }
  }else{
      return "Enter a Number";
  }

};

}]);
```

and binding:

```
<div ng-controller="game">

<input type="text" ng-model="number">

<h1>{{fizzBuzz(result)}}</h1>

</div>
```

It can't get 'FizzBuzz'but 'Fizz' and 'Buzz' ..

That works with plain js good. I just can't see if this is a sytax error..?

Live: http://jsfiddle.net/huguxvmx/1/

Thnx in advance!

Comment: The title suggests you already know the error in your code...

Comment: Its condition problem. Add your condition in reverse order. It will solve your problem. Check in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/huguxvmx/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set up this condition

```
if(($scope.number % 3 == 0) && ($scope.number % 5 == 0))
```

on the first place and replace `&` on `&&`.

This is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huguxvmx/3/).

Answer (score 2):

because else if work in this way, if one of you condition get succeeded, then next not get executed remove else and do it with only if or move the last check to top and use `&&`:

```
  if(($scope.number % 3 == 0) && ($scope.number % 5 == 0))
  {
    return $scope.result = "FizzBuzz";
    alert($scope.result);
  }
  if($scope.number % 3 == 0)
  {
    return $scope.result = "Fizz";
  }
  if($scope.number % 5 == 0)
  {
    return $scope.result = "Buzz";
  }
```

Comment: You are not checking if $scope.number is entered.. First if statement is: if a number is entered check if it can be divided 3...etc

Comment: @Mar thats upper check I have just written inner code of that condition.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative way to do FizzBuzz in Angular. Just thought I add my 2 cents in case anyone is looking to do this exercise another way.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.10" data-semver="1.3.10" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.10/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <h1>FizzBuzz</h1>
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="number in numbers">
        {{ number }} 
        <span ng-if="number%3==0 && number%5!==0" >Fizz</span>
        <span ng-if="number%5==0 && number%3!==0">Buzz</span>
        <span ng-if="number%3==0 && number%5==0">FizzBuzz</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

And here is the script:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    function range(start, stop, step){
      var a=[start], b=start;
      while(b<stop){b+=step;a.push(b)}
      return a;
    }
    $scope.numbers = range(1, 100, 1);
}]);
```